# Is there any User-Interface available for interaction with database within WSO2?

Tags: wso2, wso2-data-services-server, wso2-esb

WSO2 is capable to provide Query Browser to interact with database. But our requirement is to interact with database within WSO2 through User-Interface. Means we should Perform CRUD(create,reading,update,delete) operation through User-Interface, we don't have to write query for that.
Is that feature is available with in the WSO2???

Answer (score 0):

There is no inbuilt UI to support database CRUD from WSO2 products. You have to use a 3rd party tool for that purpose.